# How to retrieve information of one column from one table and use it in two columns of different table?

Tags: mysql

I have a User table

```
CREATE TABLE User (UserID int, 
                   Username varchar(255), 
                   Email varchar(255), 
                   FirstName varchar(255), 
                   LastName varchar(255), 
                   PRIMARY KEY (Username));
```

I want to create another table name `Friend` which has two columns `Username` and `FriendID`.

How can I use `Username` column from table `User` and use it in two different columns Username and `FriendID`?

I am using `Friend` table to have a list friends of a particular user.

Comment: instead of storing username store UserID to create relationship

Comment: The table Friend would have two columns, both of type int. The first column would be user_id, and the second Friend_ID. You would put the id of the record in table User for the user and their friend in the two fields. IOW, if user ID 1 is friends with user ID 12, the two fields would have 1 and 12 respectfully.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a string to link two records. They can change, and even slight changes will break the relation. Like changing one letter to lower case. If you use the int ID of the record to link to the User table, then if the user name changes, the relationship still works.

Comment: Just FYI; many of databases use the word `user` as a command so it may not be acceptable to have a table named "user"